# Netlogo Get a pushing force from all neighbours within a distance

Tags: math, netlogo, physics

For each turtle, I got an agentset called *visible-neighbors* which are the turtles within a distance.

I wanna get a pulling force on this turtle from each of visible-neighbors. And then sum the forces. For each single pulling force from one neighbor is following the equation force = 1 / distance ^ 2. My idea is to decompose the force to x and y components and then sum the forces on x and y, finally compose the force again.

Here is the code I have at the moment. It's runnable, but for some reasons it doesn't work.

```
to get-direction-naive
  set visible-neighbors (other turtles) in-radius 75 with [ distance myself > 0 ]
  ifelse any? visible-neighbors
    [let distance-list [distance myself] of visible-neighbors
     let x-cors [xcor] of visible-neighbors
     let x-diff map [? -> ? - xcor] x-cors
     let x-forces (map [ [a b] -> a / (b ^ 3) ] x-diff distance-list)
     let x-sum sum x-forces
     let y-cors [ycor] of visible-neighbors
     let y-diff map [? -> ? - ycor] y-cors
     let y-forces (map [ [a b] -> a / (b ^ 3) ] y-diff distance-list)
     let y-sum sum y-forces
     ifelse y-sum = 0
      [ifelse x-sum > 0
        [set heading 0]
        [set heading 180] ]
      [set heading atan x-sum y-sum]
    ]
    [right random 360]
end
```

Any advices would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What are you finding that isn't working? You want the turtles to be pulled towards each other, is that correct? This seems to set turtles' headings as needed- I think you can drop the two nested `ifelse` statements, though. Check out this toy version:

```
to setup
  ca
  crt 20 [
    setxy random-xcor random-ycor
    pd
  ]
  reset-ticks
end

to force-pull
  ask turtles [
    let visible-neighbors other turtles in-radius 10 
    ifelse any? visible-neighbors [
      let distance-list [distance myself] of visible-neighbors
      let x-cors [xcor] of visible-neighbors
      let x-diff map [ ? -> ? - xcor] x-cors
      let x-forces force-calc x-diff distance-list
      let x-sum sum x-forces
      let y-cors [ycor] of visible-neighbors
      let y-diff map [? -> ? - ycor] y-cors
      let y-forces force-calc y-diff distance-list
      let y-sum sum y-forces
      set heading atan x-sum y-sum
      let hyp sqrt ( ( x-sum ^ 2 ) + ( y-sum ^ 2 ) )
      fd e ^ ( -0.5 * hyp )
    ] [
      right random 360
    ]
  ]
  tick
end

to-report force-calc [ dif-list dist-list ]
  report ( map [ [ a b ] -> a / ( b ^ 3 ) ] dif-list dist-list )
end
```

It seems to me that the turtles face the calculated heading properly and get drawn together.

Comment: But isn't it possible that y-sum equal to 0? If y-sum is 0 then we can't get the angle through arctan.

Comment: @Minhong `atan` in NetLogo gives the absolute heading towards the point described by `x` and `y` relative to the calling agent. As an example, if the `x-sum` is 5 and the `y-sum` is zero, your turtle would want to head directly right. If you do `atan 5 0`, you correspondingly get a heading of 90.